# Loop through files in a Kubernetes pod from a bash script

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I'd like to create a script to copy a batch of files from a folder in a Kubernetes pod to a local folder. Is there a way to loop through the files in the pod such that this would work?

```
for filename in my_pod:/src/app-data/temp/*.csv; 
    do echo filename;
done
```

This simply prints `my_pod:/src/app-data/temp/*.csv`, I think because it's not actually finding the directory I'm pointing it to. I've confirmed that the folder exists and the path is correct.

Comment: I believe you'll need to use `kubectl` to execute the command on the pod in which the filesystem resides. You could redirect that output to a file, and then loop that in your local script. It would look something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084476/kubectl-ls-or-some-other-way-to-see-into-a-pod).